# VirtualBoxで「Ubuntuをインストール」選択後、黒い画面にカーソルのみが表示されて先に進まない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

添付画像①の画面で、メニュー4番目の「Ubuntuをインストール(I)」を選択
↓
添付画像②に遷移し、そのまま何も起こりません。
どうすればよいでしょうか？

## 環境

### 本体環境

- windows 10 pro
- プロセッサ: i7-2600 3.4GHz
- メモリ: 8GB
- Oracle Virtual Box 6.1

### 仮想マシン環境

#### 一般

- オレペーティングシステム: Ubuntu(64-bit)

#### システム

- メインメモリ: 2048MB
- プロセッサ: 2

#### ディスプレイ

- ビデオメモリ: 16MB
- グラフィックコントローラ: VMSVGA

#### ストレージ

- コントローラ:IDE
- IDE セカンダリマスタ: [工学ドライブ]ubuntu-ja-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso(2.61GB)

## 試したこと

- Ubuntu isoファイルの再ダウンロード＆Virtual Box仮想マシン再作成

---

添付画像①
[image: 起動時のメニュー画面]

添付画像②
[image: 「Ubuntuをインストール(I)」選択後の画面]

Comment: 黒い画面で 右矢印キー を押すとなにか文字が表示されませんか？ もしくは、「インストールせずに試す」を選ぶとどうなりますか？ / 仮想マシンを使う場合はホスト環境のスペック (特にメモリ容量等) も念のため記載があると良さそうです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。本体環境のスペックについて追記しました。

Comment: お使いの環境でHyper-VやWSL2は利用されていますか？VirtualBoxはWindows Hypervisor Platformには対応していますがかなり不安定な印象です

Comment: Hyper-Vを設定していました。変更してみます。

Comment: ネットワーク設定で、①割当: ブリッジアダプタ 名前: Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection で行っていました

Comment: 当時はHyper-Vを設定していた記憶があるのですが、項目がありませんでした。②割当; NAT でも試行してみましたが、同じように黒い画面でとまってしまいました。

Comment: 「インストールせずに試す」を選んだ場合でも、同様に黒い画面で止まりました。